# Angular2: How to inject a service into another service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I need to inject a service1 into a service2 like described below:

```
@Injectable()
export class myFirstService { 
    method1() {}
}

@Injectable()
export class mySecondService { 
    constructor(private service1: myFirstService) {}
    method2(){
      this.service1.method1();
    }
}
```

But an error occurred with this message :

**Cannot read property 'method1' of undefined**

please does any one resolve this issue without changing main.ts or bootstrap method?

thanks a lot

Comment: Where and how do you provide the services?

Comment: You have a typo `private service1 myFirstService` should be=> `private service1: myFirstService` you don't have the `:`

Comment: yes, private service1: myFirstService

Answer (score 0):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  providers: [myFirstService, mySecondService],
  ...
})
class AppModule {}
```

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor(mySeconService:MySecondService) {}
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Try using each service in a separate file, 
so the bootstraper can load service1 first independently

Comment: make sure you provide the servise1 first

Answer (score 0):

Check for proper imports of service into another service file and check for module file for providers.

```
"http://plnkr.co/edit/skVuGMuN5npaiwM70idS?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts"
```